# Short science fiction story about a soldier in a war between two robotic nations

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

The story follows a humanoid robot soldier in a battle and describes how he clears a house using his high-tech weapons and then collects the body parts of the slain enemies in a sack to be "recycled" later and made into new soldiers to fuel the never-ending war.

The story also shows the commander of this army (also a robot), sitting in a room, reading and analyzing the reports of the war coming from all around the world.

At the end the soldier dies and and the leader receives the report of his demise.